# Radiator drain plug for Ford Falcon BA Mk2 Wagon

Tags: ford, radiator

I'm trying to flush the coolant on a 2005 Ford Falcon (BA Mk2 wagon model, with the 6-cylinder engine), but am having difficulty locating the radiator drain plug.

I'm having difficulty even getting to the underside of the radiator, in fact, as there is a black plastic splash-guard secured to the underside of the front bumper.  The guard was attached with a handful of bolts which were easily removed, plus some clips which slip over the bottom lip of the bumper, which were also easily removed.  It also has a couple of seemingly cheap plastic bolts affixed to it (one on each side) which are now the only things still holding it in place.  These I can't figure out how to remove.  The plastic bolts look vaguely like they might be slotted for a phillips screwdriver, but I tried that and the bolts just spin loosely without coming out.

So my questions are, how do I remove these two bolts to get the splash-guard off, and once I've gotten the splash-guard off, where is the radiator drain plug/what should I look for in order to find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it doesn't have a radiator drain plug.  To flush the coolant you have to remove the bottom radiator hose.

As for the plastic bolts on the splash guard, if you mangle them enough you can slip the splash-guard off of one of them and then pivot it around the second and out of the way.  I used a flat-head screwdriver to pry one of the bolts slightly out, and then a pair of pliers to strip material off the head of the bolt until it was small enough to just slide the splash-guard off of the remaining stub.